# Pattern matching equivalent variables in Haskell, like in Prolog

Tags: haskell, syntax, prolog, pattern-matching, unification

In prolog, we can do something like the following:

```
myFunction a (a:xs) = ...
```

This is, when the 1st argument of `myFunction` is the same as the first item of the list that's in the 2nd argument, this function will evaluate to `...`.

My question now is... how to accomplish a similar thing in Haskell?
I have the idea that Prolog's Pattern Matching is more expressive than Haskell's. I've been trying to code that in Haskell and I'm having trouble -- either I am using invalid syntax or the above trick will simply not do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Haskell doesn't do this kind of "variable matching". You'll have to explicitly put a guard on:

```
myFunction a (x:xs)
    | x == a = ...
```

Answer (score 12):

Haskell doesn't do *unification* of variables, as Prolog does. As the [Haskell 98 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.3.1) says,

> The set of patterns corresponding to each match must be linear---no variable is allowed to appear more than once in the entire set.

You can of course name the variables, and state they must also be equal:

```
f a (b:_) | a == b = ...
```

---

Interestingly, Agda does let information flow across patterns like this, and introduces a special notation `f x (.x:_)` to say that this `x` must be that `x`.

Comment: In scala you can use `x` to denote a pattern that matches the value of a variable like the agda case as well.

Answer (score 8):

In Haskell, you can't do implicit comparisons like this in a pattern match. Instead, you'll need to add a guard which explicitly does the comparison, like so:

```
myFunction a (b:xs) | a == b = ...
```